# MongoDB Aggregation Date Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a query in MongoDB which is suppose to pull records based on certain criteria. I think I may be misunderstanding how the aggregation pipeline functions. The query in questions is pulling records correctly for the most part but it is bringing in some records that do not match the criteria. It seems to be the date portion of the query that is causing this and I think I may be doing it wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Query:

```
var theFirst = new Date("2016", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0");
var theLast = new Date("2017", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0");

var query = [
    { $match: { $and: [{ "ProjectName": { '$regex': '^((?!win).)*$', '$options': 'i' } }, { "ProjectName": { '$regex': '^((?!Champion Cooler recommended).)*$', '$options': 'i' } }] } },
    { $match: { $or: [{ "Payments": { $exists: true } }, { "Reports": { $exists: true } }] } },
    { $match: { $or: [{ "Payments.ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gt: theFirst } }, { "Reports.ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gt: theFirst } }] } }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'winorganizations',
            localField: 'OrganizationId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'orgitem'
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            OrgName: '$Organization',
            Address1: '$Org_Info.Address1',
            Address2: '$Org_Info.Address2',
            Address3: '$Org_Info.Address3',
            OrgCity: '$Org_Info.City',
            OrgState: '$Org_Info.State',
            OrgZip: '$Org_Info.Zip',
            TaxID: '$Org_Info.TaxId',
            orgitem: '$orgitem',
            OrgContactName: "",
            OrgContactEmailAddress: "",
            GrantContactName: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Contacts.Name", 0] },
            GrantContactEmail: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Contacts.Email", 0] },
            GrantNbr: "$WINNbr",
            AmtApproved: "$Amount",
            DateAccepted: "$DateAccepted",
            ProjectName: "$ProjectName",
            ProgramArea: "$ProgramArea",
            Initiative: "$Initiative",
            Strategy: "$Strategy",
            ProgramOfficer: "$programOfficer",
        }
    }
];
```

This works for the most part except the third line `{ $match: { $or: [{ "Payments.ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gt: theFirst } }, { "Reports.ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gt: theFirst } }] } },` I want all documents where Payments (embedded array) have a scheduled date of `greater than $gt` 01/01/2016 AND `less than $lt` 01/01/2017 OR Reports (embedded array) have a scheduled date of `greater than $gt` 01/01/2016 AND `less than $lt` 01/01/2017

It is pulling a document where it has a Report with a scheduled date of 12/30/2017 which obviously meets on part if the criteria but its like its ignoring the $lt. Ideally this record should not be returned.

One of the documents it is return has a report collection like this:

```
"Reports" : [ 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "eah",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "eah",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2013-12-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "received emailed image",
        "ReportTypeId" : "12",
        "ReportType" : "ACK",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2013-12-10T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "MH",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "MH",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2014-11-03T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Reports recevied and sent to MH 10.31.2014",
        "ReportTypeId" : "6",
        "ReportType" : "F,N.",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2014-11-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "n/a",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "n/a",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "12.22.16 MH approves Second no-cost extension. First no-cost extension was due 2/1/2017. Original due date was 12/1/15. Umut Ozek asked MH for a 1 year extension for the term of the contract and a 2 year extension on the final report. See email in Report folder.",
        "ReportTypeId" : "30",
        "ReportType" : "FINAL",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2017-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "TG",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "TG",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2014-06-06T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "need original",
        "ReportTypeId" : "12",
        "ReportType" : "ACK",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2014-01-10T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }
]
```

One of the reports is greater than 01/01/2016 but it is not less than 01/01/2017.I need the query to only pull where the date lands between those two dates not either or.

Here is a reports array that I would expect to return if I were to use `$elemMatch`. As you can see toward the bottom there is a report that is 12/31/2016 which should match our criteria but it does not return.

```
 `"Reports" : [ 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "DKO",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "DKO",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2007-03-19T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2007-03-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2008-03-16T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Gave to Nac",
        "ReportTypeId" : "9",
        "ReportType" : "N.",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "NGW",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "NGW",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2009-01-16T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Financial Activity Rpt",
        "ReportTypeId" : "7",
        "ReportType" : "F.",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "NGW",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "NGW",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2009-03-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "2008 Annual Rpt",
        "ReportTypeId" : "17",
        "ReportType" : "ANNUAL",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "NGW",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "NGW",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2010-01-08T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "19",
        "ReportType" : "UPDATE",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "n/a",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "n/a",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2011-01-07T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Gave to Nac",
        "ReportTypeId" : "19",
        "ReportType" : "UPDATE",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "NGW",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "NGW",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2012-01-09T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Investments down.",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "sn",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "sn",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2014-01-02T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "n/a",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2013-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "NGW",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "NGW",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2012-05-05T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Annual report, overall foundation investment down from 2011.",
        "ReportTypeId" : "17",
        "ReportType" : "ANNUAL",
        "ScheduledDate" : null,
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "n/a",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "n/a",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "AB",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "AB",
        "ApprovedDate" : ISODate("2016-05-06T05:00:00.000Z"),
        "Note" : "Received via email 5/6/16; Reviewed with SN",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2015-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Complete",
        "ReportStatusId" : "6eebae88-fca3-4b21-ad80-283eeb564f3f"
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2016-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2017-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2018-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2019-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "ProgramOfficer" : "",
        "ProgramOfficerId" : "",
        "ApprovedDate" : null,
        "Note" : "",
        "ReportTypeId" : "26",
        "ReportType" : "ENDOWMENT",
        "ScheduledDate" : ISODate("2020-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"),
        "ReportStatus" : "Pending",
        "ReportStatusId" : ""
    }
],`
```

Comment: Please add an example document that reproduces the problem. The `$match` in the question resolves to true if there is at least one Payment or Report matches the condition.

Comment: I added a collection that is pulling that shouldn't be pulled. The is is that the $match is not functioning properly that should be a $lt and $gt together but its only using one which looks like the $gt.

Comment: Does the document have anything in Payments array? It is an `or` condition, which means if either of arrays has a matching item, it resolves to true.

Comment: You require `$elemMatch`. Something like `{ "Reports": { $elemMatch: { ScheduledDate: {$lt: theLast, $gt: theFirst } } } }` to match the both the criteria against each report's `ScheduledDate` element. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents

Comment: When I do $elemMatch it actually doesnt return anything.

Comment: Can you add the document which you are expecting the `$elemMatch` on `Reports` to return ?

Comment: @Veeram I have added the array of reports in one of my documents that I would expect to return with $elemMatch which does not.

Comment: Is your date portion of the query a date type  versus date string ? The query will return the document for something like `{ "Reports": { $elemMatch: { ScheduledDate: {$lt: new Date(2017-01-01), $gt: new Date(2016-01-01) } } } }`

Comment: Oh I see, so instead of doing Reports.Scheduled date I need to treat it as an object. I think thats where I got it wrong.

Comment: It total works now! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple thanks to @Veeram. I needed to be using `$elemMatch` and when using that I need to treat embedded arrays as iterative objects in my query.

Final working code:

```
var query = [
{ $match: { $and: [{ "ProjectName": { '$regex': '^((?!win).)*$', '$options': 'i' } }, { "ProjectName": { '$regex': '^((?!Champion Cooler recommended).)*$', '$options': 'i' } }] } },
{ $match: { $or: [{ "Payments": { $exists: true } }, { "Reports": { $exists: true } }] } },
{ $match: { $or: [{ "Payments": {$elemMatch: {"ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gte: theFirst } } } }, { "Reports": {$elemMatch: {"ScheduledDate": { $lt: theLast, $gte: theFirst } } } }] } }, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'winorganizations',
        localField: 'OrganizationId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'orgitem'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        OrgName: '$Organization',
        Address1: '$Org_Info.Address1',
        Address2: '$Org_Info.Address2',
        Address3: '$Org_Info.Address3',
        OrgCity: '$Org_Info.City',
        OrgState: '$Org_Info.State',
        OrgZip: '$Org_Info.Zip',
        TaxID: '$Org_Info.TaxId',
        orgitem: '$orgitem',
        OrgContactName: "",
        OrgContactEmailAddress: "",
        GrantContactName: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Contacts.Name", 0] },
        GrantContactEmail: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Contacts.Email", 0] },
        GrantNbr: "$WINNbr",
        AmtApproved: "$Amount",
        DateAccepted: "$DateAccepted",
        ProjectName: "$ProjectName",
        ProgramArea: "$ProgramArea",
        Initiative: "$Initiative",
        Strategy: "$Strategy",
        ProgramOfficer: "$programOfficer",
    }
}
];
```

You will see on the third line where I use `$elemMatch` and that works.